# How do I type correctly a wrapper function?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Assume following declarations:

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T')

def wrapper(fn: Callable[..., T]) -> Callable[..., T]:
    ...

def identity(a: T) -> T:
    ...

@wrapper
def w_wrapped(a: T) -> T:
    ...

@identity
def i_wrapped(a: T) -> T:
    ...
```

The two annotated functions can be used like this:

```
def apply(fn: Callable[[str], int]) -> int:
    # types fine:
    val1 = fn(i_wrapped(''))
    # mypy complains: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "T"; expected "str"
    val2 = fn(w_wrapped(''))
    return val1 + val2
```

What's wrong with the `Callable` type? I can use `Callable[..., Any]` instead of `Callable[..., T]` in the `wrapper` declaration. But I feel like this partially defeats the purpose, I would like to declare that when you use the wrapper with `str`, the result would be `str`, not just anything. There may be other workarounds too, but is this mypy limitation or my misunderstanding?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what your desired annotations are. ``Callable[..., T]`` is a function that receives *anything* and returns a ``T``, but all your functions receive *one ``T``* and return a ``T`` – that would be ``Callable[[T], T]`` and preserve e.g. "returns a ``str`` if it receives a ``str``". Does ``wrapper`` actually have apply to *all* ``* -> T`` or just to ``T -> T``? The first seems useless for your usecase, but the latter is only the identity function (+ arbitrary side effects) which seems equally useless.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That's actually a valid point. The wrapper does not really care about argument types nor return type (I'd say this is often the case for pretty much any wrapper, or *decorator*); the problem is that type like `Callable[A, B]` is not valid, variadic generics are not supported (as noted in the bug reports linked to by @joel), anything else would be too restricting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there may be two things going on here:

Firstly, a mypy bug, see [this](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7033) and [this](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1317)

Secondly, `Callable[..., T]` is too loose. Specifically, there's no connection between its argument and its return value. As a result, with `@wrapper`, `w_wrapped` becomes a `Callable[..., T]`, with no constraint on its argument, and the output of `w_wrapped('')` is a unbound `T`, which can't be passed to `fn` which expects a `str`.

You have a number of options depending on your use case, including

- `def wrapper(fn: Callable[[U], T]) -> Callable[[U], T]:` for `U = TypeVar('U')`, though I believe the mypy bugs stops this working. `U` could also be `T`
- `def wrapper(fn: C) -> C:` for `C = TypeVar('C', bound=Callable)`. This doesn't have the problem of `Any` because you're *bounding* on `Callable` so you retain the type signature. However, it will limit your implementation of `wrapper`, short of `type: ignore`

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I was looking for. Though I would kind of disagree with that *`Callable[..., T]` is too loose*; well, it is, actually, but there is no better option.

Comment: @volferine you may find it easier to work with `C = TypeVar('C', bound=Callable)`, and force the type checker in the implementation of `wrapper` (unless you want to change your parameter types). Then your API will be well-behaved

Comment: That gives the same result as if I used plain `Callable`, without any type parameters. It types fine, but not under strict mode. And it is more or less equivalent to `Callable[..., Any]` which types fine even in the strict mode, but...

Comment: @volferine in what way? Bounding to `Callable` means the decorator returns a function with the same signature it decorates. You don't lose any type safety. [You can see that here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=a2fde3251da193383732d71fd762cf75)

Comment: You are right, it is better indeed. And to placate mypy in the strict mode, it works to use `bound=Callable[..., Any]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you write Callable[..., T], I believe the editor is not able to correlate "..." with "T".
"apply" fn is expecting a str, w_wrapped is returning a str, but this process is happening inside "wrapper" inner logic, since "..." is not relatable to T, the editor is dealing with two different T's, like T_0 and T_1. Maybe thats whats causing type mismatch.

Comment: That does not seem correct. First, a type checker does not (need to) go into the function body for checking function applications if the function is typed; sometimes the body is not even available. Second, for one application of the generic function there is nothing like "two different T's", note that for the type `T -> T` there is no such problem.